# Jquery calendar util

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm just wondering if there is a jquery calendar util.
I tried searching at http://api.jquery.com/ but I can't find anything. It seems that jquery miss this or maybe I'm just missing something.

If jquery doesn't have this, can some one share/recommend a good jquery calendar util / plug-in?

P.S.
my goal is to have string name of months through JSON: sample (0 -> january, 1 -> february, ...)

Comment: many calendar plugins.. API not best place to search plugins....try google

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has a datepicker -> http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

A lot of modern browsers have built in date pickers, so you may only want to use the jQuery UI datepicker if the browser doesn't support it.  See http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-browser-datepickers-within-minutes/

Answer (score 1):

There is the jQuery UI [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline).

jQuery UI still needs the core jQuery library though.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)